# How to organise and rank observations of a variable?

Tags: sorting, dataset, stata, rank, cumulative-sum

I have this dataset containing world bilateral trade data for a few years.
I would like to determine which goods were the most exported ones in the timespan considered by the dataset.

The dataset is composed by the following variables:

- "year"
- "hs2", containing a two-digit number that tells which good is exported
- "exp_val", giving the value of the export in a certain year, for that good
- "exp_qty", giving the exported quantity of the good in a certain year

Basically, I would like to get the total sum of the quantity exported for a certain good, so an output like

```
hs2  exp_qty
01   34892
02   54548
...   ...
```

and so forth. Right now, the column "hs2" gives me a very large number of observations and, as you can understand, they repeat themselves multiple times (as the variables vary across both time and country of destination). So, the task would be to have every hs2 number just once, with the correspondent value of "total" exports.

Also (but that would be just a plus, I could just check the numbers by myself) it would be nice to get a result sorted by exp_qty, so to have a ranking of the most exported goods by quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might be a start at what you need.

```
collapse (sum) exp_qty, by(hs2)
gsort -exp_qty
```

`collapse` summarizes the data in memory to one observation per value of hs2, summing the values of exp_qty. `gsort` then sorts the collapsed data by descending value of `exp_qty` so the first observation will be the largest. See `help collapse` and `help gsort` for further details.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked perfectly!
Exactly what I needed